# How to organize the collection according to a certain rule?

Tags: c#, linq

I have class:

```
 public class ClassA
 {
   public String ClassName {get;set;}
   public int ClassId {get;set;}
   public Guid UID {get;set}
  }
```

Where 'ClassName' may be: A,B,C,D and 'ClassId':10,20,30,40;

And unordered collection:

```
List<ClassA> unorderedCollection=GetCollection();
```

And I want to organize the collection in the following order:

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

or from `ClassId`:

1. 10
2. 20
3. 30
4. 40

Values can be completely different and they are not related to each other.
For example, a class with index 10 is not associated with a class with index 20.

So, for example:

```
   List<ClassA> unorderedCollection=GetCollection(); 
    /* has values:
      {
         B,
         20,
         uid             
      },
      {
         B,
         20,
         uid
      },
      {
         A,
         10,
         uid             
      },
      {
         A,
         10,
       uid             
      },
      { 
         C,
         30,
         uid             
      },
      {
         D,
         40,
         uid             
      },

    /*
```

And **ordered** collection should be:

```
   /*
     {
         A,
         10,
         uid             
      },
      {
         A,
         10,
         uid             
      },
      {
         B,
         20,
         uid             
      },
      {
         B,
         20,
         uid             
      },
      {
         C,
         30,
         uid             
      },
      {
         D,
         40,
         uid             
      },
  */
```

I try to use `OrderBy` but I did not manage to achieve the desired result.

How i can do that?

Comment: In the example, the 'keys' seem to be synchronized A:10, B:20, C:30, D:40.  Is this always so? If it is, then why do you need to sort by one or the other, why not always sort by, say, `ClassId`.  If they are not always synchronized, then where would, say B:10, go in the list?

Comment: "And I want to organize the collection in the following order:... OR from classId" Do you mean you want to specify the property on which you want to order? or did you mean THEN BY instead of OR?

Comment: @AlanT, yes, A =10 always. 10 is ClassId, so it doesnt change

Comment: I mean that they must be ordered in the order listed: first class A, then B, then C, and so on.
This is not alphabetically ordered

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

> `ThenBy` method after `OrderBy` to sort the collection on another field in ascending order.

```
 unorderedCollection.OrderBy(x => x.ClassName).ThenBy(y => y.ClassId);
```

Comment: This code sort collection by ClassName, but not an needed order.
For example, at my collection,after this code execute:  first values will be B, then A, then C and so on.
But i mean, that first values at collection sould be A , then B and so on.
For example, if i want to order it like: D,A,B,C this code can not do that.

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/jeffjohnson9046/2c4e35a082bb0abf74db

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           List<ClassA> unorderedCollection= new List<ClassA>() {
               new ClassA() { ClassName = "B",  ClassId = 20, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
               new ClassA() { ClassName =  "B", ClassId = 20, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
               new ClassA() { ClassName =  "A", ClassId = 10, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
               new ClassA() { ClassName =  "A", ClassId = 10, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
               new ClassA() { ClassName =  "C", ClassId = 30, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
               new ClassA() { ClassName =  "D", ClassId = 40, UID = new Guid(new byte[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0xA,0xB,0xC,0xD,0xE,0xF})},
           };

           List<ClassA> results = unorderedCollection.OrderBy(x => x.ClassName).ThenBy(x => x.ClassId).ToList();


        }


    }
    public class ClassA
    {
        public String ClassName {get;set;}
        public int ClassId {get;set;}
        public Guid UID { get; set;  }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want to order by the ClassName in a non-alphabetic way we can use a `Comparer`.

Say we want to sort the `ClassA` objects by class name in the order B,C,A,D we can use the following

```
private class ClassAComparer : Comparer<ClassA>
{
    private IDictionary<string, int> _lookup = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"B", 1},
        {"C", 2},
        {"A", 3},
        {"D", 4},
    };

    public override int Compare(ClassA x, ClassA y)
    {
        return _lookup[x.ClassName].CompareTo(_lookup[y.ClassName]);
    }
}
```

Which we use

```
//...

var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(n => n, new ClassAComparer());

//…
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it!
Here is answer:

```
    _orderClasses : {A:0, B:1,C:2,D:3}  //0,1,2- is an target order

       var indexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _orderClasses.Count; i++)
        {                            
            indexes.Add(_orderClasses[i].Name, i);
        }

        var results = _unOrderedResults.OrderBy(x => indexes[x.ClassName]).ToArray();
```